# did <verb> and <verb>

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, conjunction-reduction

While reading *A Dance with Dragons* by George R. R. Martin, I came across the following line which seemed odd to me. *(Note, English is only my third language so "seemed odd to me" is about as meaningless as it gets)*

> [...], even if he did look like a monstrous yellow slug and smell of piss.

The *smell* part is what seems off to me, though I realize there's an assumed repetition of *he did*. I guess I just find it sounding odd.

Is the used phrasing correct? Is it also correct to use the following line?

> [...], even if he did look like a monstrous yellow slug and **smelled** of piss.

Which way is most common in English?

Comment: On the principle that associated verbs forms should be in agreement, the "standard" version for OP's alternative would be *even if he* **looked** *like a monstrous yellow slug and smelled of piss*. Though as a UK traditionalist, I'd go for **smelt** anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are possible. In the original, as you say, *he did* is understood. You could also write:

> ... if he did look like a monstrous yellow slug and did smell of piss.

In your example, only the subject *he* is understood and so you would still need to mark the verb as past. Personally, I don't like the combining of the two different forms of the past tense with *and*.

For example, I don't like:

> He *did go* home and *ate*.

This is essentially what your second sentence is.

A better comparison would be:

> He is walking and talking on his phone.
>
> He is walking and is talking on his phone.

To me, both are equally correct, but the first is much more common in English. The repetition of the auxiliary verb *is* (or any other auxiliary for that matter) is more common when there is a large separation between the two verbs. There is no simple rule as to which is the most common.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, it's fine. This is a case of ordinary Conjunction Reduction from

- *even if he did look like a monstrous yellow slug and* **even if he did** *smell of piss*.

Emphatic *do*, like all usages of *do*, must be followed by an infinitive, not a tensed verb, at least if Conjunction Reduction has applied. But clearly **something** must have applied to delete the subject of *smell*, as well as the *even if* introducing the *smell* clause.

In addition, this sentence has parallel uses of two [Flip Sensory verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), *look* and *smell*. Flip Sensory verbs have subjects referring to the **source** of a sense experience, rather than to its **experiencer**, like *see, hear, listen,* etc. do. This is a rather nice parallel structure, something which always makes a sentence slide down easier. And it's another reason why they ought to be inflected alike: to maintain the conjoined Verb Phrase structure.

Answer (score 1):

I would have used "smelled" myself, but there's nothing wrong with the sentence as it stands. Martin writes in an affected style, characterized by some as "Wardour Street English," of course; still, consider this clause:

> Even if he did lie, cheat and steal ...

All present-tense verbs, and no problem anywhere. It's the disproportionate size of the first verb's complement compared to the second that makes the sentence feel funny.

Comment: What does "size of the first verb's complement" mean?