# To hear something makes it audible, to see is visible, so what are touch and smell?

Tags: word-choice

As the title states, if sound is audible, light is visible, what is a smell? And what is an object when you touch it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Smell is [olfactible](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/olfactible)

Touch is [tangible](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tangible)

Comment: _Tangible_ is very common, and _touchable, hearable, seeable_ are possible, though less common, in special contexts. _Olfactable_ is very rare, though it may exist in dictionaries; I think most people, if they reached for a single word (with no pejoration like _stink, reek, smell_), would say "smellable". The [sense verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) don't have all possible terms available.

Comment: Tangible is correct, but it's often used to discuss the concreteness of a concept or feeling. Consider describing a nanobot sitting on the tip of your finger.  Is it "barely tangible" or "barely tactile"? Tangible might carry two meanings: (1) beyond your ability to perceive such a magnificent creation, (2) beyond your ability to perceive it through touch.  Tactile is more clear in this case. //////// I like olfactible if you're cornered into you using it. "She stuck her nose even deeper into the blossoms insisting that beauty is always olfactible." Haha, maybe.

Comment: I would have said "smelly".

Answer (score 18):

Things capable of being seen are visible, things capable of being heard are audible, things capable of being touched are tangible or palpable, things capable of being smelled are odorous, things capable of being tasted are gustable.

Gustable is rarely used and primarily in technical settings.  The concept is most often expressed as "tastable" when we reach for the concept in common usage.  Because of the "-ible" "-able" endings of the other sensate adjectives, "odorous" is an unexpected form but a perfectly correct expression of the concept (though today most of us are more likely to use "malodorous" to describe a bad smell than to use the word "odorous" itself).

Some prefer "palpable" to "tangible" for things capable of being touched because tangible has slipped into being a synonym for the more general and inclusive "sensible", particularly in the use of the word in the practice of law.

Answer (score 8):

Another option to Frank H's answer would be

Touch: [tactile](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tactile)

Smell: [fragrant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fragrant) / [pungent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pungent) / [fetid](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fetid) (depends on experience)

Answer (score 2):

'Smellable' is a legitimate, though perhaps not a very euphonious adjective. Other alternatives are 'aromatic' and 'odoriferous'.

'Palpable' is the most germane one for touch.

Answer (score 2):

See - Visible/(Seeable*)

Hear - Audible/(Hearable*)

Smell - Olfactible (used very rare)/Smellable

Taste - Edible (for food)/Potable (for water)/(Tastable*)

Touch - Tangible/Palpable/Tactile/(Touchable*)

*Note: They can be used but word on the first column (except for olfactible) are commonly 
used, but smellable is rather used than olfactible

Answer (score 0):

Remember that some things are **tastable** or **edible**.

I would also think that some poorly-defined proprioceptive feelings, like earthquake phenomena, are **sensible** (in the generic)