# "to lie deep" vs "to lie deeply" - is "is certain it must lie very deeply" incorrect?

Tags: linking-verbs

In *[A_Treatise_of_Human_Nature](https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/4705)*, of David Hume, it is written:

> For if truth be at all within the reach of human capacity, it is certain it must lie very **deep** and abstruse: and to hope we shall arrive at it without pains, while the greatest geniuses have failed with the utmost pains, must certainly be esteemed sufficiently vain and presumptuous.

I [gathered](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+must+lie+very+deep%2Cit+must+lie+very+deeply&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=50) that [the usage seems to be](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+must+lie+deep%2Cit+must+lie+deeply&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=50) *to lie deep* instead of *to lie deeply*. Why does an adjective follow the verb *lie* instead of an adverb? Is *lie* here a [linking verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_verb)? Would the phrase *It is certain it must lie very **deeply** and **abstrusely**.* be incorrect?

Comment: For the same reason you say "stand tall", "lie dead", etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of "play" followed by an adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239971/use-of-play-followed-by-an-adjective) Admittedly, the depictive adjective 'deep' is usually followed by a prepositional phrase when used after 'lie': 'The wreck lay deep in the ocean'. And 'lie abstruse' seems outlandish. // See also [Can adjectives make adjuncts modifying verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102666/can-adjectives-make-adjuncts-modifying-verbs/102682#102682)

Comment: The tennis umpire sits highly above the court?  No.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It does, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a linking verb in your quotation:

> CONDITION [***linking verb***] to be in a particular state or condition -
> ***lie empty/open/hidden*** etc.
>
> - The book *lay open* on the table.
> - The town now *lay in ruins*. ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lie#:%7E:text=5%20condition%20%5Blinking%20verb%5D%20to,town%20now%20lay%20in%20ruins.))

***Lie very deeply and abstrusely***, would not be incorrect grammatically, but it would change the meaning of the sentence: While *deep* and *abstruse* are predicative adjectives modifying the subject (*truth*), ***deeply*** and ***abstrusely*** would describe *the way in which the action of **lying** is performed*, that is, it would modify the verb, it would not describe the subject.

Moreover, the use of *lie + deeply* as an action verb is less common than *lie + deeply + participle*, where *lie* is again a linking verb and *deeply* modifies the past participle that follows it:

> - The oldest sequence is not exposed but ***lies deeply buried***. (*[U.S. Geological Survey Professional Paper](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/U_S_Geological_Survey_Professional_Paper/NVrwAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22lies%20deeply%22&pg=PA130&printsec=frontcover)*)

Here's an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lie%20deeply%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) that sheds some light on this:
[image]