# The verb 'has' in 'Kim has courage' vs in 'Kim has a car'

Tags: verbs, linking-verbs

Consider

[1] a. *Kim has courage.*

         b. *Kim has a car.*

**My question:** Is there a known linguistic concept that captures the difference (that I seem to be detecting, as explained below) in the usage of the verb *has* in these two sentences?

**What CGEL says**

According to [CGEL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) (p. 111), the verb *has* in [1a] and [1b] appears in the same function, which they call 'stative' (the actual example CGEL gives is *She has many virtues/two sons*). But it seems to me that there is something quite a bit different in the way *has* functions in these two sentences---maybe not syntactically different, but certainly semantically. I'll try to explain what I mean in two different ways.

**Explanation of what I mean in terms of 'linking verbs'**

I understand that linguistics does not find the category of 'linking verbs' a useful one (or even a well-defined one), as has been discussed e.g. [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124810/what-are-all-the-words-that-make-up-a-complete-list-of-linking-verbs-in-english). But if we suspend our disbelief (if any) in linking verbs for a second, we might want to say that in [1a] ***has* acts as a linking verb**, whereas in [1b] it does not.

It is true that 'linking' to lone adjectives (as in *A rose is red*) is a hallmark of linking verbs (as traditionally defined), and yet *has* can never 'link' to (or be followed by) a lone adjective---at least as far as I know. But it is also possible to 'link' to noun phrases. So, for example, in

[2] a. *Kim is a zombie*

         b. *Kim has a zombie,*

[2a] is predicating of Kim that it has a certain property, namely, that she is a zombie. If you ask the question, "How many 'entities' are implied to exist by this sentence?", the answer is **one**, namely Kim. The zombie is not a separate entity; the zombie *is* Kim. All of this is very consistent, I think, with what friends of the concept of linking verbs would say is characteristic of that category. Also, the verb *is* in [2a] can be replaced by another linking verb (some that would work include *remains, seems, becomes, turns*, ...), and the resulting sentence not only makes sense, but its meaning is, in some sense, related to the meaning of the original sentence with *is*.

In contrast, the sentence [2b] implies the existence of **two** entities: Kim and the zombie. It further says that a certain relation exists between, namely that of 'having', or of 'ownership', or of 'possession'.

**Explanation of what I mean in terms of properties vs two-term relations**

An alternative explanation is to say that in [2a], *has* expresses a **property** (or a **one-term relation**) of Kim's, whereas in [2b], it expresses a **two-term relation** between Kim and the car. Properties and relations belong to [analytic philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/) (for relations, see the section [relations](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/#Relations)). They are (therefore) accompanied by one or another degree of controversy, so they are not the firmest foundation on which to build an analysis (which should be, well, scientific, or so one would hope...). But I haven't yet figured out a better way to explain why I think [1a] and [1b] use *has* in rather different ways.

**Now what about [1]?**

The sentence [1b] clearly implies the existence of two 'entities', Kim and the car, and asserts that the relation of possession exists between them. Things aren't as clear in [1a]. You could, I suppose, say that *courage* is also an entity, and that *has* again expresses a two-term relation. But that is not at all my 'mental picture' of [1a]. When I say that *Kim has courage*, I mean that Kim is courageous, no more and no less. To my mind, there is no action of *possessing* here that is in any way comparable to the clear case of possession in [1b].

Further evidence that [1a] is different: if *has* is replaced by at least some of the verbs that are traditionally thought of as linking verbs, the sentence that results is at least marginally sensical, and moreover its meaning (such as it is) is related to the meaning of the original sentence. Consider e.g. replacing *has* by *is*: *Kim is courage*. I agree that it is somewhat dubious whether this makes sense. But it can be fixed by expanding it to *Kim is the very definition of courage*, which definitely does make sense. And this expanded version would also work with *is* replaced by *seems, becomes, remains,* and many other traditional linking verbs. Substituting *has* back produces *Kim has the very definition of courage*, which is again a bit dubious, but becomes less dubious if replaced by  *Kim has what is the very definition of courage*.

This process does, in fact seem to reach a fixed point. Both of the following seems grammatical, sensical, and in fact mean the same thing:

[3] a. *Kim **is** what seems to be the very definition of courage.*
    
         b. *Kim **has** what seems to be the very definition of courage.*

I take this to be evidence that at least in [3], *has* is as much a 'linking verb' as *is* is.

So while the replacement of *has* by other linking verbs and vice versa (in sentences like [1a]) certainly does not go through completely smoothly, nevertheless there does seem to be some sort of pattern there. It is just a bit trickier a pattern than what we are used to with traditional linking verbs.

**A summary**

The verb *has* seems to serve two rather different functions in [1a] and in [1b]. Those who like linking verbs might say that *has* is a linking verb in [1a] but not in [1b]; those who like the philosophical concepts of properties and relations might say that in [1a] *has* expresses a property of Kim's (that she is courageous), while in [1b] it expresses a two-term relation (one of possession of a car by Kim). Either way, *something* seems to be relevantly different about *has* in [1a] vs in [1b]. My question is: is there a known linguistic concept that captures this difference?

**A bonus question for those who like the concept of linking verbs:** do you agree that *has* in [1a] is a linking verb?

Comment: I fear you may be overthinking things a bit.  It's a common enough trope to personalize characteristics as entities separate from an individual, and once we do that we can make those entities subject or objects in their own grammatical right.  We speak of *buying* courage, *taking* courage, *borrowing* courage, etc.  Are we to consider *these* linking verbs?

Comment: ***has*** has exactly the same meaning in both. What is different is the semantics of what it means to have a quality attribute vs a physical object.

Comment: @Jim Thank you for your comment. But, what about the interchangeability of _has_ with _is_ in [3] (which I just added)?

Comment: In that last bit you've got two different senses of "definition".  One is "epitome" while the other is "quality".

Comment: @deadrat Thank you for your comment. 1. _borrow_ maybe indeed could be a 'linking verb' in this usage. After all, if _have_could, in some rare cases, act like a linking verb, why couldn't other verbs?  2. having said that, _take courage_ is a phrase, a separate entry in a dictionary. One can _have courage/pluck/gumption/chutzpah_, but one can't _take_ any of them. 3. Yes, maybe _courage_ is reified in [1a]... but that's not the mental image I, at least, have. Maybe it started as a metaphor, but it doesn't strike me as one when I use it. And I think  [3] may count as evidence for that.

Comment: @Hot Licks Thank you for that comment. However, I don't see how _quality_ could work there: _Kim has what seems to be the very quality of courage_ doesn't sound right---does it? In contrast, at least to my ear, _Kim has what seems to be the very epitome of courage_ sort of does... at least to me...

Comment: Your example 3 isn't idiomatic in the sense you want. 3b would mean that Kim is holding a slip of paper on which she has copied the definition of *courage*.  Kim is a person, not a definition, although she could be the epitome or an exemplar.  But then *has* doesn't work for these words.

Comment: *One can have courage/pluck/gumption/chutzpah, but one can't take any of them.*  No, but one can get all of them, at least in the past tense.

Comment: Also note that as clumsy as it is, *has courage* may be transformed into passive voice:  *The courage that **was had** by the coward could be found in a bottle of cheap scotch.*  By the way, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: @deadrat 1. as far as _get_ vs _take_: that's perfectly fine; after all, _get_ is already on many a list of linking verbs. 2. I agree that [3b] can be interpreted as you suggest. But I think it can also, given the right context, be interpreted as equivalent to 'she is very courageous'. One just has to imagine a conversation like this: A: _Kim is skittish._ B: _No way, she has courage._ A: _I say she's kind of a coward._ B: _And I say..._ (and then says [3b]). 3. I didn't think you were the downvoter, but thanks for confirming it.

Comment: @deadrat 4. I think the passivization is the most serious objection so far. In reply, maybe one could say it only works through abuse of language---but, then again, maybe not.

Comment: @deadrat One could also say that, OK, _has_ is definitely not a typical linking verb (e.g., as I already said, it doesn't work with adjectives). Maybe, in its case, the passive can also perform a 'linking' function (which is after all not really a syntactical category, for reasons explained in the link I provided above, but somehow a semantic one)---i.e. one can say that the passive is just a figure of speech and no actual action of 'having' is taking place. But I do have to sleep on this. Thank you!

Comment: I agree they mean something different. *Kim has courage* means something similar to *Kim is courageous*.

Comment: @Araucaria Right. It ascribes a **property** to Kim; it says of Kim that it enters a **one-term relation**. In contrast, _Kim has a car_ says that _Kim_ and _a car_ enter a **two-term relation**. Now, is there a linguistic concept for things that express one-term relations as opposed to two-term ones?

Comment: @linguisticturn Maybe a question for stack linguistics? I don't know of one, but I'm rubbish at semantics stuff (very unfortunate given the thesis of my PhD!)

Comment: @linguisticturn I'd make your question much shorter though!

Comment: @Araucaria Another way to phrase the question, following deadrat's comments is this: in [1a], is _courage_ reified_ or not? I don't know how to test for such things--and maybe they aren't really testable...

Comment: @linguisticturn Reified or not. The semantics is different, it seems to me.

Comment: @Araucaria 1. I agree that shorter questions are better, but when I was writing it, I was quite confused about many things. I still am, but as I receive feedback from various people, I will better understand what matters and what doesn't, which will eventually enable me to make the question shorter. 2. Stackexchange is against duplicate questions on different stackexchange sites... I will have to rephrase the question somehow. Maybe after I learn more on this site, I'll be able to reformulate it sufficiently to post on the linguistics stackexchange.

Comment: @Araucaria 3. I was actually curious what the people who like the concept of a linking verb would say about [1a]. Judging by the discussion of some of the other questions posted, I know that at least some people on this site do like that concept. On the linguistics stackexchange, I think I would simply be told that the whole concept of a linking verb doesn't make any sense to begin with---that there is just the copula _be_, and that the other traditional linking verbs have to be analyzed in all kinds of disparate ways, as e.g. [here](https://goo.gl/mXxn1r).

Comment: @linguisticum If you drastically rephrased the Q, then I doubt it would be regarded as a duplicate. You could also consider deleting this question here (you could reopen it later if you wanted to).

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks---I may do that! Let me think about it for a bit.

Comment: I don't see the grammatical pattern.  Try "Kim has courage (in his heart/in his liver/in every part of him)."  You're dealing with folk theories about the seat of a quality, not grammar.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, *has* is not a linking verb and no, you haven't come close to showing that it is.

The long answer is that you seem to be confused about what a copula does. Traditionally it shows that two items have the same referent (*The Evening Star is Venus*); membership of a class (*He is a teacher*); or some kind of property (*The rose is red*). Higgins(1973,1979) refined this a bit to four functions: predicational (*The cat is big*), specificational (*The detective is Sherlock Homes*), identificational (*That is John*), and equative (*Kim is a zombie*).

You haven't shown *has* performing any of these functions of a copular verb, so the obvious conclusion is that it isn't one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1. I was careful to not claim that _has_ functions as a **copula**  in [1a]. My understanding is that the traditional category of linking verbs includes copulas, but also other kinds of verbs. 2. It is true that if  _has_ doesn't (in usage [1a]) qualify as a linking verb, then I would like to know why. However, my primary question is whether there is _some_ category recognized by linguistics that would distinguish the usage in [1a] from that in [1b].

Comment: Then perhaps you should tell us how you define 'linking verb', but note that by doing that you essentally reduce your whole argument to a search for a self-serving definition of 'linking verb' that gives you the result you want. 1a and 1b are the same. Kim posseses something, in both cases signalled by 'has'. Anything differences are in the semantic properties of the words used, not in 'has'.

Comment: To repeat, my **main** concern is not to defend or expand the category of linking verbs (which linguists say is ill-defined anyway), but rather to understand if [1a] and [1b] are really the same usage of _have_ or not. And it does still seem to me that [1a] predicates a property to Kim, whereas [1b] expresses a two-term relation between Kim and the car. If this is so, then I would think that this distinction might be something that linguists have already studied; and if _that_ so, then I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: As far as linking verbs, just to play the Devil's advocate: one definition says that they are 'verbs that describe the subject or link the subject to some complement such as a predicate adjective or predicate noun'. It seems to me that a fair rephrasing of that is that linking verbs are those that express the fact that the subject has a certain property (as opposed to expressing the fact that the subject enters into a two-or-more-term relation with other things). That's the semantic part.

Comment: The syntactic part is that they must either take a direct object or require a complement that is either an adjective or an NP (this is so as to exclude the intransitive verbs that also predicate a property to the subject, as in _He hungers_).

Comment: The term ' linking verb' is used very loosely by some people. It can range from strictly being the 'be' verb, through the traditional 'be' plus a variable bunch of perception verbs, through to the concept that a sentence is a collection of arguments linked by verbs so all verbs are linking verbs. It would be helpful if you clarified what you mean  when you say linking verb.

Comment: As for 1a and 1b, 'has' is being used in the same way. The alleged differences you point to are functions of the nouns used, not the 'has'. Courage is an abstract noun applicable only to an individual, while car is a concrete noun with a tangible external referant.