# Is it I'm feeling good or I'm feeling well?

Tags: grammar

Isn't feeling here a verb of being so you would use the adjective good?

Comment: (a) _Feeling good_ is the usual phrase. (b) _Feeling_ is not a "verb of being"; there are no such things. Rather, _feeling_ is a [sense verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), representing personal sensory perception and its metaphoric extension (as in _feeling sorry_). (c) _Feeling well_ means 'feeling not sick', in a discourse where sickness is a topic. Executive Summary: Don't believe everything you read in old grammar books.

Comment: They mean "stative verb" by "verb of being", it's the way it's called in some languages.

Answer (score 10):

You could use either, depending on the context.

1) "Feeling well" refers to feeling healthy, not being sick, etc.  If someone asks "How are you feeling?", they are generally inquiring about your health, so it's appropriate to answer this way.

2) "Feeling good" is more of a general state of mind, so "I'm feeling good" can refer to someone feeling happy, optimistic, proud, etc.  You can say "I'm feeling good about my science project; I think I'll get an A" or "I'm feeling good about helping that old lady this morning."  And if someone says "How are you?" and you want to describe a general good mood, you can say "I'm feeling good" (or just "Good").