# Can I drop the word "like" in certain instances?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

The particular example I am thinking of here is: "This sounds like a noble pursuit." I was wondering if it would be grammatically correct to drop the *like*: hence, "this sounds a noble pursuit."

It sounds correct in my head and out loud (much to the confusion of my co-workers) but I don't think there's any grammatical precedent. Is it actually correct? If not, are there times when I *can* drop the 'like'? What would those times be?

Comment: The important thing is that this construction only occurs in complements of sense verbs (_look, sound, feel, smell, taste, seem,_ for instance).

Comment: "This sounds a noble pursuit" sounds fine to me, though I might say "this *seems* a noble pursuit". (I speak Australian English, if it matters.)

Comment: @nnnnnn John Lawler's comment above is relevant. "Seem" is another of his "sense verbs" which behaves in the same way as "sounds".

Comment: You're welcome. Links to sense verb stuff [are here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/160924/15299).

Comment: "I could say I did what I had to when I left you to go pirating, **but it would taste a lie** to say it wasn't what I wanted." - Bootstrap Bill Turner, Pirates of the Caribbean

Comment: Not sure *Pirates of the Caribbean* can be taken as an example of modern English usage.

Comment: How can one be sure this isn't 'to be deletion'? "This sounds to be a noble pursuit." cf "He appears Ø sane.'

Answer (score 0):

While you might see "**like**" dropped in literary works (to sound more poetic?), you would never drop the "**like**" in regular, every-day spoken or written American English.

Comment: At least not with a noun; "this sounds silly" is obviously fine, but "this sounds like a silly idea".

Comment: @swmcdonnell I would like to see a source to support this claim as it relates to this question.

Comment: '$50 seems a lot to pay' sounds like it merits the 'every-day spoken American English' tag to me.

Comment: I would say, "$50 seems like a lot to pay."

Answer (score 0):

You can correctly say either "this sounds like a noble pursuit", or "this sounds a noble pursuit", but it's not a case of dropping a word (or, in grammatical terms, "ellipsis"): rather those are **two different ways** to say the same thing.

"This sounds a noble pursuit" is a copular construction (like "this idea seems bad", or "I am a police officer") -- where the two things on the opposite sides of the verb are identical.

Comment: Hello, equin0x80. They are certainly 'different ways to say the same thing', but why should that rule out (perhaps first occurring so far back in history that the _when_ isn't clear) ellipsis? One could argue that the original could be 'this sounds to be a noble pursuit' rather than 'this sounds like/as if it is a noble pursuit'. // If the claim that deletion is  maintained, it is necessary to give a respected reference in support.

Comment: "This looks like gold" and "This looks to be gold" certainly don't mean the same thing, Are you sure what "This looks gold" means? Is it really gold?