# Can "look" be transitive in the meaning "look at"?

Tags: verbs, word-usage, transitivity

For example:

> He examined the body indifferently, much like one would look a dead animal on a roadside.

I would like to know if *to look* can be employed transitively like this. I'm sure I've read it used in this way before, but my search was inconclusive. (I know I could write "look at" or "look over", but I'm curious about that particular possibility in the example.)

Comment: That is not a usage I've ever seen before. Looks quite bizarre to me. Of course you can look worried/happy/odd/a mess, etc., but that's a different sense of the verb _look_.

Comment: The active volitional [sense verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) _look_, like _listen_, requires a preposition with their object. _Look_ takes _at_, while _listen_ takes _to_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Modulo frozen fossils like *look daggers at someone*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Though it would probably be understood, native speakers would regard it as a mistake.

Comment: I figured it was probably be a mistake, thanks for clarifying =)

Answer (score 0):

Using *look* as a transitive verb is so easily understood that I suspect it will be an accepted usage in a decade or so.  I've lived through so many meanings of *virtual* that I've lost count.  Language changes and those great marks you (or I) earned in English grammar aren't going to be worth horse manure compost when we are gone.