# How can I describe a passive type of touching?

Tags: speech, sense-verbs

If I touch an item (like a book) intentionally, I might say

> I touch the book.

Now, if this had happened without my being aware of it, I would not say that *I touched it*, but I also would not say that *the book touched me*.

How should I describe this situation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say. If you accidentally touched the book without meaning to (or realising), then you still touched the book. What does this have to do with passive? Also, you should take a look at our sister site, [ell.se]; this question looks like it would be a better fit there (though it still needs editing to make clear what you're actually asking).

Comment: I mean,, how can I say in correct form, that "book touched me" ?

Comment: You can say, “The book touched me”, but that would mean that you found the context of the book very emotionally moving when you read it. Otherwise, I still don't see what's wrong with “I touched the book”—that's what happened, after all.

Comment: "I brushed against the book"

Comment: @Mitch You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would also say *I touched the book*.
Although it's a strange thing to say, because what does it matter?
Books exist to be touched, after all, and especially to be read.
If it matters to you that it's accidental, say *I touched the book accidentally*.

*Touch* is a ***[Sense Verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299)***, and they have special syntactic affordances.
You're talking about the **Volitional** versus the **Non-volitional** varieties of sense verbs.

**Volitional** means something you do on purpose. **Non-volitional** means you did it accidentally.
It's the difference between *spill* and *pour*. English doesn't usually distinguish volitionality 
in its active verbs. In some cases one can tell, and in others it doesn't matter.

But sense verbs are special. The long-distance senses, sight and hearing, both use different verbs
for volitional (*listen, look*) versus non-volitional (*hear, see*). They're all active verbs, and the non-volitional ones are transitive (*He saw/heard her*), but the volitional ones are intransitive, and require a preposition (*He looked **at**/listened **to** her*). The other senses are less distinctive.

Answer (score 5):

If a book is sitting on a table, and you reach out and make contact with it, you do touch the book. But if the book is sitting precariously on the table, and falls off and makes contact with your leg as you walk by, without any action on your part, then, in theory, you could say that the book touched you. The problem with this is that "touch" has an alternative meaning relating to emotions, as Janus Bahs Jacquet explained, and the most likely conclusion one would reach if you told them the book touched you, is that you were emotionally moved by the book in some fashion.

So, the solution in this case is to choose another word. If the impact of the book on your leg was slight, you might use the verb "grazed", as in, "I'm all right; it only grazed me"; or if the impact was somewhat more forceful (or it was a large book), then you might use the verb "hit", as in "The book hit me; that hurts."

Comment: Q: "Were you touched by *Love in the Time of Cholera* ?"  A: "Touched, I was knocked out, it fell on me b******g head."

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to switch tense:

> I suddenly realized that the book and I were touching.

This doesn't place any intent on either object involved (you or the book).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the idea of touch sounds intentional alone, thus just adding an adverb would suffice, such as ... I accidentally/mistakenly touched the book.

It does sound slightly foreign in speech, using the word touch by accident, so 
perhaps refer to ...I accidentally knocked/brushed/moved the book.

Or switch perspective, and start I didn't realise that I had touched the book.

Answer (score 0):

> I brushed against the book

implies that I didn't purposefully touch the book. I may have felt it or not.

'Touch' gives the connotation, whether active or passive, of someone being aware of/feeling the touching.