# Can we use "bad" as an adverb in writing and formal speech?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, formality

Should a lecturer say

> "He felt bad" or "He felt badly"?
>   "His tooth ached so bad he couldn't sleep" or "His tooth ached so badly he couldn't sleep"?

Are both forms acceptable in formal speech?

Comment: Use **badly;** there is no reason to misuse an adjective when the adverb exists!

Comment: 'Bad' (as an adverb) is informal. Use 'badly' in formal speech.

Comment: You *"feel bad"* if you are sick. You *"feel badly"* if you have a poor sense of touch. Would you say *"I feel happy"* or *"I feel happily"*; *"I feel sad"* or *"I feel sadly"*?

Comment: Use whichever one is correct (see the extended discussion at the previous thread). In 'He felt bad [...]', the predicative adjective is **required** if the sentence mirrors eg 'He felt cold'. Using 'bad' as an adverb (His tooth ached so bad he couldn't sleep) is not a formal usage, though.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My question is about formal speech.

Comment: My answer is about the two different constructions involved. Whatever the register. But "His tooth ached so bad he couldn't sleep" (where 'bad' is indisputably forced into duty as an adverb) sounds distinctly informal or even slang to my British ears.

Comment: Sense verbs of a certain type take **adjectives *not* adverbs**. “You look/sound/feel/smell/taste good/bad.”

Comment: @tchrist: These are called _[sense verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299)_, not "verbs of a certain type".

Comment: @JohnLawler  I was trying to dodge around the *see/look* and *hear/listen* issue, because I forgot how to call the one side of those two. I guess they’re active in that they (can) take direct objects.  Those ones don’t take predicate adjectives.

Comment: They're transitive in that they can take direct objects. Transitive verbs may or may not be active (though actives are probly in the majority). As for predicate adjectives, that's a different story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when someone says they feel *bad*, it's expressing an emotion. The confusion here is due to the fact that *feel* is both an action verb and a linking verb.

A quick test on whether a verb is linking or an action verb is the *am* test.

In this sentences, you can replace *feel* with *am*.

> "I feel bad" becomes "I am bad"

Since you can make the verb swap, you know that *feel* is a linking verb describing a state. *Bad* is an adjective, and you use adjectives to describe linking verbs.

When using badly in this form, you can't replace *feel* with *am.*

> "I feel badly" becomes "I am badly"

This swap doesn't make any sense. Since you can't make the swap, you know that *feel* is an action verb in that sentence; it's describing an action.

In short, "I feel bad" describes a state of being, whereas the use of *badly* should be used to describe an action, such as "he smells badly".

Comment: “Adjectives describe linking verbs”? How does that work?  I think you mean that they take adjectival complements, but that doesn’t mean those adjectives describe those verbs. Try it with *poor* and *poorly*.

Comment: Linking verbs are more subtle. They describe emotions or states of being. The verb “to be” is the linking verb most people know about. When you say “I am bad,” you're describing your state. You can think of linking verbs as linking a subject to its state. Forms of “to be” include “is,” “am,” “was,” “were,” and “are.”

Comment: "He smells badly" means his nose does a poor job of distinguishing odors.  If you mean he exudes an offensive scent, you should write, "He smells bad."