# Intransitive verbs with preposition in passive sentences

Tags: transitive-verbs, passive-voice, intransitive-verbs, sense-verbs

The words *listen*, *shout*, etc. are intransitive verbs, but why are they used in passive sentences with preposition *to*, *at*, etc.?

e.g:

> she was never listened to.
>   I don’t like to be shouted at.

When intransitive verbs are used with preposition, are they considered as transitive verbs?

Comment: Lots of intransitive verbs with prepositions can be put into the passive. They're still considered intransitive verbs.

Comment: *I listened to her. I shouted at you.* Where's the passivity?

Answer (score 12):

The mistake is believing that "intransitive" is an invariant property of verbs.

Transitivity is a property of **clauses**, not of verbs. Many verbs cannot be used alone in a transitive clause, and therefore transitivizing prepositions are used to make them transitive. These prepositions don't even have their usual meaning -- they're just crutches used to produce a transitive clause. [Sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) are a good example.

- *Bill heard the sonata.* (transitive)

---

- *Bill listened for an hour.* (intransitive)
- *Bill listened **to** it for an hour.*  (transitive)

---

- *Mary saw the painting.*  (transitive)

---

- *Mary looked for an hour.*  (intransitive)
- *Mary looked **at** it for an hour.*  (transitive)

Clearly the preposition *to* in the third sentence does not mean what *to* normally means.
Likewise, the preposition *at* in the last sentence is not a normal use.  Both are governed by the verb.

When a verb is transitivized by adding a preposition, the transitive verb is the `V + P` combination,
and it can be passivized like any transitive verb

- *They looked at/listened to/thought about/argued over/made much of **it** for decades.* (active)
- ***It*** was looked at/listened to/thought about/argued over/made much of for decades. (passive)

Comment: **Very well put.**

Comment: Are you saying that the third sentence has a structure like *Bill [listened to] [it]* rather than *Bill [listened] [to it]* ?

Comment: No. I'm not saying "rather than". I'm saying "in addition to".

Comment: @Araucaria The French cunningly have a single-word verb which maps across to 'listen to'. But I'm assuming John Lawler is referring to the different degrees of 'binding' [my term here] between simplex verb and prepositiony-thing.

Comment: Not my term. But it does have a metaphoric sense that describes it reasonably. This is a syntactic linkage, different from but not entirely dissimilar to the linkage between verb and particle in phrasal verbs like _look up_. Those follow different rules and are easily distinguished from prepositions because they can be shifted and can't occur with pronoun objects. _She looked at the book/it_ vs _She looked up the book/*it_.

Comment: In both cases the verb and the particle/preposition/adverb chunk can form a constituent which overlaps another constituent; both arrangements are available to the speaker and listener to play with as they please.

Comment: This answer states "Transitivity is a property of clauses, not of verbs" and then (confusingly)  ends by talking about transitivity  as being a property of verbs: "When a verb is transitivized by adding a preposition, the transitive verb is the V + P combination,
and it can be passivized like any transitive verb."

Comment: @Clare *Transitivity* seems a word in need of a common, agreed-upon definition here for these discussions. For various reasons I don't know that it would be good enough to say that it's simply any verb with one or more non-subject NP arguments. For one thing, that might let verbs like *be, seem, become* that take “predicate nominatives” as their arguments sneak in and break something important on us like passive inversion. But that seems closer to what John means when he says that adding a preposition to intransitive verbs lets them become transitive, since now they can accept an NP argument.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Which French verb were you referencing? Also, what is 'cunning' about it?

Comment: @Canada - Area 51 Proposal The French verb écouter is transitive, so _écoute-moi!_ (= _listen to me!_) doesn't take a preposition. / I'm saying that this makes rather redundant the 'is P a real preposition here?' debate in this particular (French) case. I'm representing the development by the French of the single-word transitive verb (I don't actually know how or why it happened; there was probably no intention to simplify analysis involved) as a clever analysis-simplifying device.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth +1. Thanks for the elucidation!

Comment: Hi John, I hope you don't mind my edits. I thought adding some `hr`s made the intransitive-transitive groupings clearer. Feel free to rollback if you disagree.

Answer (score -1):

A transitive verb is a verb which has a *direct object*. (e.g. I saw the *car*, I ate the *food*)

A prepositional phrase does not count as a direct object, so both transitive and intransitive verbs can have prepositional phrases.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Transitive verbs take two arguments. The second argument can be a nominal phrase, or a preposition phrase or even a verb phrase. To say transitive verbs can only take nominal objects is nonsense.

Comment: @curiousdannii If you agree J Lawler's post above is accurate then you agree that clauses and not verbs are in/transitive. A prepn itself is not a DO, and of course neither is a prepositional phrase. To the extent that some verbs tend to take DOs and others PCs and others other types of complements with different semantic roles then epicfaace is not wrong. *Shout at someone* for example has a verb which takes *at* as a complement, *at* takes a noun as complement. The noun, which could be considered object of *at* is NOT a complement of the verb *shout*.

Comment: @curiousdannii What I meant was that transitive verbs are the only verbs that _can_ have a direct object. Both transitive/intransitive verbs can still have phrases.

Comment: Both of you are either using these terms wrong or in ways I've never seen, but probably wrongly. There is a crucial difference between arguments and adjuncts. Transitive verbs take two arguments, which can be various types of phrases. And I might not agree with jlawler. Many verbs do have a strict number of arguments they can take, and though there are valence changing constructions they are marked. You can't transitivise *sleep*!

Comment: You can't "sleep it off"?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Hah, well done, though I'd say that's either a different word/phraseme or at the least a different sense. Just like *sleep on it*. Related, but distinct from *sleep*.

Comment: ...or, indeed, *sleep your way to the top*, which actually involves very little sleeping.

Comment: How about ["I've not slept a full nights sleep in over ten years"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=BROWM+TOAST&oq=BROWM+TOAST&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.2613j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22SLEPT+A+*+SLEEP%22&tbm=bks&start=50).