# "Can see" or "see"?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs, sense-verbs

In the song "Me Neither" Brad Paisley sings:

"...would you like to dance
Me neither I was just bein' polite
Thank goodness my feet are much too tired
I'm sure you're tired too, **I can see an empty booth**
Would you like to maybe sit and talk a while
Me neither"

Would **I see an empty booth** be correct in this sentence and what would be the difference?

Comment: It's really just a stylistic choice. If you want to micro-analyse, you could say including ***can*** implies that *maybe not everyone else sees*, or maybe that you yourself *couldn't* see whatever is important until the time of speaking. So it's a sort of attention-getting "intensifier".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Alethic (or 'able to') sense of *can*, has -- [predictably for a modal](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf) -- lots of strange grammar.

In this situation, specifically,  *`Subj` can `Verb`* means the same as *`Subj Verb`*.

This is  true of [sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) (e.g, ***see, hear, feel, sense, smell, taste***). With most sensations, if  you **can** sense something, at some place and time, then you **are** in fact sensing it, there and then.

The only other verb I know of that this is true of is ***speak***, in the sense of *speak a language*.
For some reason, the generic verb phrase *speak Spanish* in

- *They speak Spanish.*

without further qualification -- like *at home* -- is taken to mean the same thing as

- *They **can** speak Spanish.*

Comment: I think in some contexts *understand* works the same as *can* in this respect (unsurprisingly, given the semantic overlap). So *"I [can] understand his lectures"* can apply to past, present, and/or future lectures, with or without ***can***.

Comment: Yeah, _understand_ works there; I think the closer it gets to a human sensation, the more likely it is to work that way.

Answer (score 1):

To me both are grammatically correct. However, the main difference lies in their certainty. One of them is more likely to happen than the other. What I'm saying is that if you use "I can see" it means that by this moment, there's an empty both, but perhaps there won't be none later.

On the other hand if you say "I see" it's more common because you can see for instance the sun rising everyday, you see that there many booths but maybe none of them is empty. Yet you're still seeing them.

Answer (score 0):

The word **can** does not add any significant semantic element to the line, and isn't more or less correct.  But the purpose off adding that word is simply the meter of the song.  Without it, the line is one syllable too short.