# Can a linking verb be transitive?

Tags: verbs, copular-verbs

I found the following example on [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/feel_1). This is from the first entry of the verb *feel*. A pattern 'feel something' is given under this entry, while the verb 'feel' is listed as a linking verb. Does it mean a linking verb can be transitive? (There is also a sense which is explicitly listed as transitive.)

> **1** *linking verb*
>   to experience a particular feeling or emotion
>
> + adjective
>   *The heat made him feel faint.*
>
> feel something
>   *He seemed to feel no remorse at all.*
>
> ...
>
> **3** [transitive] (not usually used in the progressive tenses)
>
> feel something
>   to become aware of something even though you cannot see it, hear it, etc.
>   *Can you feel the tension in this room?*

Comment: I'm not quite sure what OLD mean by a "linking verb", but yes, _transitive_ is a term of syntax, and syntactically _feel no remorse_ is transitive because it has a Noun phrase as a direct object. The semantics of this expression are different from in their meaning 3, though.

Comment: _Feel_ is a [Sense Verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), and it is one of those that come in three grammatical varieties: Volitional (_I listened to/felt it very carefully_), Non-Volitional (_I heard/felt something just now_), and Flip (_That sounds/feels strange to me_). The Flip subject is the source of the perception, and its human receiver is in a prepositional phrase, or unspecified _to me_. It looks like the auxiliary _be_ of a predicate adjective, but it's actually a case of [Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), like _seem_ or _appear_.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an error in the dictionary's listing.

The verb *to feel* has a transitive sense and a copular sense.  When copular, its argument is a subject complement.  When transitive, its argument is an object.

In the sample sentence for the questionable entry, the verb is copular.  However, that verb is *seemed*.  The infinitive *to feel* in this sentence has a direct object and is used in its transitive sense.  There is no grammatical difference between "to feel no remorse" and "to feel the tension".

Saying that a verb is transitive is the same thing as saying that the verb has an object.  Saying that a verb is copular, or a linking verb, is the same thing as saying that the verb has a subject complement.  Certainly a verb can be transitive in one use, copular in another.  It can't be both transitive and copular in the same use.

Comment: They probably mean the same thing by "linking verb" that you do by saying it has a "copular sense". Neither of these is precise terminology, and neither is the same as "auxiliary verb". That's why I don't use "linking" or "copula" as grammatical terms for English; they're imprecise and nonstandard, even though some consider them The Real Deal, certified by [The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html).

Comment: Yes, "linking verb" and "copular verb" are synonyms.  To me, it is a precise term.  Copular verbs cannot be cast in the passive voice, and they take subject complements as their only argument.  It's terminology like "sense verb" and "action verb" that I find to be imprecise.

Comment: They also appear in questions, tags, equatives, comparatives, perfects, and passives. You may find sense verb and action verb imprecise, but that's because you don't know their definitions.

Comment: Presumably one could call a copular/linking verb a "description verb": "He feels embarrassed"; "she looks cold"; "the car is blue". That's not the same sense as "he feels embarrassment"; and *that's* not the same as "he felt her touch".