# resemble = look like... ??? = sounds like... ??? = smells like

Tags: single-word-requests

The verb **resemble** is typically used to denote similarity in *appearance*. We can thus replace this verb with "look like."

But does English have analogous single-word verbs for "sound like," "smell like," "taste like," and "feel like?"

EDIT: Yes, the broad definition of **resemble** (as commenters have wisely pointed out) includes, more generally, "having qualities similar to" or "seeming like," which would include the other senses. Is it truly used for all of them? And my question remains: are there analogous single-word verbs for the other senses?

Comment: Your definition is inadequate: resemble: have a similar appearance to or qualities in common with (someone or something); look or seem like. [Google Dictionary]

Comment: Would you agree that it is "typically used to denote similarity in appearance"?

Comment: Merriam Webster defines "resemble" as "to look or be like (someone or something)." So while it is typically used for appearance, it can be used for other senses than sight. It's usually phrased slightly differently; compare "My sister resembles my mother" vs. "Her laughter resembles the sound of a river."

Comment: [Sense verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) come in a number of flavors and colors, each with corresponding grammar. _Resemble_ can refer to any sense, since a _semblance_ is simply a representation.

Comment: No; 'often used'. Google hits show a preponderence of the 'look like' sense, but check these at [BrainyQuote](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/resembles.html).

Comment: This is not a very good answer in generic terms (which is why I'm just leaving it as a comment), but in some cases, you could probably get away with using ***echo***. @Nicole’s example, for instance, works all right with that: “Her laughter echoes a flowing river” is at least evocative and quite poetic-sounding, if perhaps not exactly colloquial.

Comment: More colloquially, particularly in British English, you can use the sense verbs on their own as simple transitives: “That smells a treat”, “that sounds a nasty business”, “she looks a right slapper”, etc. Colloquial tending towards slangy, but usable.

Comment: I'd say _only_ in British English, not particularly. That construction isn't used at all in American English.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can say that such and such sound resembles something, for example:

> "It resembles a train whistle, and with some imagination, the background ambient water sounds resemble a train moving down a track." <sup>[news.discovery.com](http://news.discovery.com/earth/oceans/mysterious-underwater-sounds-that-have-stumped-scientists-140423.htm)</sup>

The same is also true for *smell like*.

Comment: Yes, you could say, eg. "The odor resembles that of a flower garden (after it's been fertilized)".

Answer (score 2):

Smells, sounds, tastes, and textures/"feels" can **imitate** others.

Outside of copyright or patent infringement cases you probably wouldn’t hear about a pair of sounds/smells/tastes/textures “imitating each other,” but one of them could certainly be described as imitating the other.  Some examples:

> Propane leaks are easy to detect due to the strong pungent **smell** **that imitates** the **scent** of rotten eggs.
>
> An onomatopoeia ... is a word that **phonetically** **imitates**, *resembles* or suggests the source of the **sound** that it describes. (note use of "resembles" next to "imitates")
>
> There are a lot of brands out there that claim their products **imitate** the **taste** of burnt tobacco almost to perfection.
>
> A kind of **visual texture** that **imitates** real **texture** by using a two- dimensional pattern to create the illusion of a three-dimensional surface. (visual texture = appearance?)
>
> … meat alternatives are products made ... into a texturized product that has a **texture** that **imitates** the chewy **texture** of meat.
>
> The surface **imitates** the **feel** of real ice and allows players another alternative when ice is unavailable.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like = **mimics** or **parrots**

Comment: That's not really the same thing. You can mimic or parrot something without sounding very much like it at all if you're not a very good mimic/parrot. And in the example given in one of the comments, both verbs would be decidedly odd: “Her laughter mimics/parrots a river”? Surely not. Mimicking or parroting is a description of the act of _trying_ to sound (or look) like something else, rather than the state of actually _sounding_ like something else.