# what does "feels" in the text imply and why does "feels" place in the position?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In one corner of the BrandLab, Jeff goes to work running VW's folks
>   through a rapid-fire succession of video ad campaigns the BrandLab
>   **feels** have worked.

I don't understand what the BrandLab "feels" about.

Also I'm not sure what "have worked" tries to tell... does it mean "a repid-fire sucession of video ad campaigns have worked well"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I parse the sentence:

There are some video ad campaigns that BrandLab consider (believe, feel) to have been effective (worked).

Jeff quickly shows (rapi-fire) people from a client VW) these video ad campaigns, or possibly shows extracts from them, giving the VW folks a rapid overview of the campaigns.

The overall sense here is one of enthusiasm and urgency. I don't see any great ambiguity here.

Comment: 'Brandlab' is used as a metonym for '[the majority of] the [important] people working at Brandlab'; this is standard. Many Brits would use '... that Brandlab feel ...' to signal the implied 'people'.

Comment: Right. The noun phrase _campaigns the BrandLab feels have worked_ comes from a relative clause _campaigns **which** the BrandLab feels have worked_, which in turn comes from the clause _the BrandLab feels **that** the campaigns have worked_. In this case, _feels_ is a generalized [sense verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), and means 'finds/thinks/believes/perceives'.