# "Appearance" is to how something looks as ______ is to how something sounds

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a generic word that describes how something sounds, or what sounds something makes (to name a concept in a computer program I'm creating).

- I've looked up ["to make a sound" in a reverse dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=to%20make%20sound), but none of the results seem to capture it.
- I feel like "Audience" or "Audition" almost capture the idea, but this is not at all how the words are used.

*"Appearance" is to how something looks as ______ is to how something sounds.*  What words can fill in that blank?

Comment: _Sound_ is the generic noun, formed from the flip [sense verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) _sound_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a technical context, it might be *acoustic signature*.

But in a general layman context where precision is not expected:

- audible characteristic
- acoustics
- energy
- synergy
- aural feel
- auricular type

and combinations of those.

Comment: I think for a single word to be used in the context of Clinton's program, *acoustics* should be sufficient. It's not technically following the dictionary definition of acoustics, but in layman's terms, AmE speakers will say acoustics versus acoustic signature.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: Good suggestion.  I added it.

Answer (score 1):

**Tone** has many meanings (source [Dictionary.com)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tone) that may fit:

- any sound considered with reference to its quality, pitch, strength, source, etc.
- quality or character of sound.
- vocal sound; the sound made by vibrating muscular bands in the larynx.
- a particular quality, way of sounding, modulation, or intonation of the voice as expressive of some meaning, feeling, spirit, etc.
- the characteristic quality or timbre of a particular instrument or voice.
- an accent peculiar to a person, people, locality, etc., or a characteristic mode of sounding words in speech.
- stress of voice on a syllable of a word.

Comment: I think tone is too specific for this context.

Answer (score 0):

*Appearance* is to how something looks as *[aurality](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aural)* is to how something sounds.

Comment: The caveat here is that aurality specifies ears/organic noise detection.

Answer (score 0):

If it's specifically for computer/digital noises, *tones* could be used quite well.