# "his mother look very tired"

Tags: grammar, tenses, verb-agreement, agreement

Is it correct to say,

> James could see his mother **look** very tired from all the chores.

The options in the test paper were the following:

1) looks 2) look 3) looked  4) had looked

I would have thought 'looking' would be the best answer but there was no such option. I read somewhere on this site that with 'can/could see', only 'looking' can be used. Not 'look'.

Comment: It's *grammatical*, but *idiomatically* I can't think of any context where a native speaker wouldn't prefer ***looking*** over ***look***. That wouldn't apply to, say, *I see you look very tired*, but I find there's there's something slightly off about conjoining references to "actual perception" *(**see, observe**)* and "appearance" *(**look, seem**)* in one "action".

Comment: If 'looking' is not an option provided, can 'looked' be an option? As in, "John could see (that) his mother looked...

Comment: Yes, but note that if we replace *his mother* with a pronoun, there's a syntactic difference between *I saw **she** looked tired / I see **she** looks tired* and *I saw **her** look / looking tired*. What context do you have in mind that makes you suggest ***looking** is not an option?*

Comment: Actually it was MCQ question with options: looks, look, looked and had looked. I would have thought 'looking' would be the best answer but there was no such option.

Comment: Then it's a stupid question. To repeat, all variations are probably grammatical (even ***had looked***, in a sufficiently contrived context).

Comment: I agree. I read somewhere in this site that with 'can/could see', only 'looking' can be used. Not 'look'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Ya might need to "unpack" that sentence of yours in your first comment; namely, "I see you look very tired," since it can be read in at least two ways: 1) as is, with the first four words implying an almost habitual perception of the one who sees, and 2) as is, with the words "I see" implying "I can see that you look very tired."  It's hard to distinguish between the two ways of reading! It's almost an evanescent moment, or a mini paradigm shift which you think you've caught, but then no . . .! Have I 'splained things adequately? Don

Comment: Yeah, but one unusual way of reading your sentence is unusual, to say the least. Keep the words the same, but understand them as follows: James is imagining his mother looking tired. In other words, it's something he can do, figuratively speaking, in his mind's eye. It's a weird reading, to be sure, but it IS possible! Don

Comment: @rhetorician: Yes, *I see you look tired* could certainly carry a range of different meanings depending on context. Not least because many people (me, at least) might be casting around for some obscure meaning to explain why the speaker didn't say simply say *You look tired*. Why bother explicitly saying that you ***see*** what someone ***looks*** like, since there's no way you could be aware of their appearance without seeing it anyway?

Comment: Can 'I see you look' and 'I could see you look' be treated with the same infinity rule?

Comment: Infinitive I mean

Comment: Grammar rules for [the sense verbs are covered here.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound good to me.

A very important issue that has to be kept in mind: there are several possible grammatical structures with the verb "see." I'll discuss three of them. I'm a little rusty on my terminology, but I'll try to describe them as best as I can. If you tell me what grammatical terms and concepts you are familiar with, I can do a better job of tailoring this answer to your question.

### With a that-clause (which has its own subject and finite verb)

It seems the test-makers intended for you to analyse the example sentence with a "that"-clause where the "that" is omitted:

> James could see [*that* [his mother __ very tired from all the chores]].

In a structure like this, "his mother" is actually the *subject* of an embedded clause that has the same structure as an independent sentence would. In other words, the verb form used here has to one that can work in the stand-alone sentence

> His mother __ very tired from all the chores.

So you cannot use an infinitive. (With this overall structure.)

This leaves the three finite forms: 1) looks 3) looked 4) had looked. The best choice out of these is "looked" because of the context of "could see".

By the way, this is also the way I would analyse the structure of "I see [that] you look tired." Here, "look" is **not** the infinitive; it is a finite verb in the present tense that lacks an *-s* suffix only because the subject (of the verb "look") is the second-person pronoun "you." The reason I say this is the following evidence: if we switch the second-person pronoun to the third-person, I would say "I see [that] **he looks** tired."

I'll also list example sentences with a pronoun in place of "her mother," which might help because the third-person singular feminine pronoun has distinct forms for subject and object:

> James could see **she looked** very tired from all the chores.

### With an object and a participle

> James could see his mother **looking** very tired from all the chores.
>
> James could see **her looking** very tired from all the chores.

In this sentence, "his mother" is an object and "looking" is a participle. That structure would be grammatical. But as you note, it is not given as an option.

### With an object and an infinitive

A third grammatical structure would call for the infinitive "look." (I didn't realize this until after I first posted my answer.)
The verb "see" can sometimes be followed by an object and an infinitive, in sentences like "I could see him run." But, that structure doesn't seem right to me here for some reason. Sorry, I guess this part is actually the core of your question!

It does seem to me that the same awkwardness is present when using other copula-like verbs:

> James could see **she was** very tired from all the chores.

is much better than

> ?James could see **her be** very tired from all the chores.

I'll try to add more about this. I hope what I have posted so far helps you to avoid confusing these grammatically different uses of the verb "see."

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I believe the intention of the question is to test the understanding of the infinitive 'look',  as in, 'I could see him run.' In this case, 'James could see his mother look very tired from all the chores.'

Comment: However, there seems to be an awkwardness about that sentence. Yes, please add more on that. Thanks.

Comment: Could the awkwardness be something to do with 'look' tired? In the general usage of 'inert perception' verbs (eg hear, see, perceive, notice, sense), we use the bare infinitive as well as the +ing form. For some cases, in choosing between bare infinitives and +ing forms, we consider momentary/completed or extended actions/actions in progress. In this sentence, 'look' is neither. It is not an 'action' that his mother actively performed but rather a look of tiredness perceived by James.

Comment: That sentence effectively means that James saw his mother's tired look and not that he could see his mother momentarily performing an action verb like snap, run, cry etc.  Therefore, to test the understanding of infinitives in the context of James perceiving (could see) his mother's physical condition, 'looking' is the best option because his mother's tired look must be an extended one and cannot be momentarily snapped out of. Otherwise, this sentence is better interpreted using 'that' clause. What do you think?

Comment: @Lyng: I think I'd agree with you.