# What's the difference between "to hear" and "to listen"?

Tags: differences

Is it the same thing to say "I'm hearing you." to "I'm listening to you."?, And what makes them the same or different.

Is to hear a song the same as to listen?

I have the idea that to hear is involuntary and listening is a premeditated action.

Comment: I’m sure this is a duplicate and also belongs on ELL if anywhere.  But to LISTEN is an attempt to hear. One can LISTEN without HEARING (shhh, can you hear that? ) and hear without listening (I couldn’t concentrate with all that noise in the background)

Comment: ELL. I suggest this is moved.

Comment: They're both [sense verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), and pattern the same way as _see_ and _look_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Hearing" is the physical activity of having sounds enter the ears and activate the auditory nerves.  "Listening" is the mental activity of sorting out the sounds and understanding their meanings.

It's generally impossible to listen without conscious effort and attention, though you can hear while your "mind is elsewhere".