# What is the name for verbs applied to the wrong subject?

Tags: verbs, american-english, terminology

For example, when one says "that apple tastes good", obviously they don't mean that the apple is tasting anything - apples can't taste. Rather, the person eating it does the tasting.

You can also see this in the southern US when people say things like "I'm gonna learn you a thing or two". The person talking in that example is teaching, not learning. The person they're speaking to is learning.

Comment: _Taste_ is a [sense verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), and they come in three flavors: experiencer-subject volitional (_look (at), listen (to), taste, smell, feel_), experiencer-subject non-volitional (_see, hear, taste, smell, feel_), and Flip non-experiencer subject (_look, sound, taste, smell, feel_). _The apple tastes good_ is a flip construction, like _It sounds/looks/feels/tastes/smells good_. So it's not the wrong subject, it's just a different construction.

Comment: John's comment would  be perfect as an answer.

Comment: The ditransitive use of _learn_ (to mean ‘teach’) used to be perfectly common and standard and has equivalents in pretty much all other Germanic languages. It's also perfectly standard in the past participle when used as an adjective: someone who is _learned_ is (by modern, standard definitions) actually _taught_.

Comment: @Centaurus [It already was](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105098/taste-is-to-flavor-as-touch-and-sight-are-to-what/105101#105101).