# Progressive or simple: How to correctly talk about what's happening (what someone's doing)

Tags: grammar

I don't know how to analyze the grammar of the following two statements:

"I don't want to keep listening to you sniffle."

vs.

"I don't want to keep listening to you sniffling."

To the point, I haven't been able to figure out if one is more correct than the other or if there's really any difference in meaning.

Comment: They're both grammatical, and the reason is that [sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) (like _see, hear, listen, look,_ etc) can take either infinitive or gerund complements (_I saw him leave/leaving_)..

Answer (score -1):

The second sentence is grammatically incorrect. Only the first sentence is correct.

However, you can make the second sentence correct by changing the "you" to a "your". This is because the "-ing" suffix is used to make [gerunds](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerund.htm), so "your sniffling" in this context can mean "the sniffles that belong to you".