# Felt nervous vs was nervous

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following correct and why?

> 1. The student felt nervous before first day of class
> 2. The student was nervous before first day class

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and mean the same thing.

> Feel
>
> 2 Experience (an emotion or sensation)
>
> ‘I felt a sense of excitement’
>
> no object, with complement
> ‘she started to feel really sick’
> ‘it felt odd to be alone again’
>
> no object
> ‘we feel very strongly about freedom of expression’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/feel

However, your example sentences contain errors.

The student felt nervous before **the** first day of class
The student was nervous before **the** first day **of** class

Comment: Yes. _Nervous_ describes an emotion, and any emotional adjective can appear as a complement to _feel_, the least specific of [the sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299); consequently _He feels nervous/scared/tired_ means the same as _He is nervous/scared/tired._