# Is it correct to say that this element is both part of the predicate and is a complex subject?

Tags: grammar, complex-sentences, predicate

"He was seen running down the street."
Is it correct to say that "running down the street" fulfills the predicate while also being part of the subject, a complex subject?

Comment: it is not part of the subject; the subject is _he_.

Comment: Well, I am talking in regards to the "complex subject" that some grammars use.

Comment: @AllexKramer, there is no complex subject here.

Comment: @LucianSava I understand this, which is why I'm asking in reference to the terminology that I have laid forth, but thank you!

Comment: @Toothrot I am sorry, but I believe you are wrong. We will see, however.

Comment: @LucianSava There are differing beliefs on that, however, and that is what I am trying to dive into.

Answer (score 2):

> - *He was seen running down the street*.

is a complex sentence. It's got two verbs (*run* and *see*) used in different forms, and therefore two clauses, one main and one subordinate.  In addition, it's had several things done to the main clause -- it's been passivized, and the indefinite agent subject (the 'somebody' that saw him) has been deleted.

Several more things have been done to the subordinate clause -- it's been made into a gerund complement clause, and its subject (*him*, as in *Somebody saw him running down the street*) has been raised to be the object of *see* which gets passivized in the main clause.

The original question asks about the gerund verb phrase *running down the street*.
For the record, this constituent is **not** the subject. Of anything.
It is **not** part of the subject of the main clause, nor of its predicate.
It **is**, however, part of the object complement clause of *see*.
Finally, *fulfills the predicate* is a meaningless phrase and has nothing to do with grammar.

Comment: The “fulfills the predicate” line should been said differently, as I assume you are part of the study that recognizes “arguments” of the predicate, like complements. However, I do not see where a gerund comes into place. Gerund is the participle form functioning as noun, correct?

Comment: @AllexKramer: _Fulfill_ is grammatically meaningless. Does a subject fulfill a verb? Does an object? Does the verb fulfill the subject? No way to tell what it might mean or how you could check. _Predicate_ is a term in logic (as is _argument_), not grammar. As for the gerund, you're confusing participial _-ing_ verb forms with gerund clause constructions, of which this is one. Gerund clauses do use participial _-ing_ verb forms, but those are verbs and don't function as nouns -- rather, the clause they are the verb in functions as a noun.

Comment: That makes sense. However, do we not just consider single-standing gerunds as clauses now also?

Comment: Also, was the gerund clause not a complement in the “original” version before being made passive?

Comment: If you are certain that a single _-ing_ form of a verb is a gerund, yes, it's the remains of a clause, a complement (noun) clause. But a single _-ing_ form is not always a gerund; [there are several other possibilities](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html).

Comment: You said “it's been made into a gerund complement clause”. But wasn’t it already a part of it before?

Comment: That depends on how one uses the metaphor. Transformations like Passive are ways to relate sentence types, not actual things that go in in speech. The "original" (i.e, least complex, most prototypical) form of the clause is abstract; it happens that it comes out as a gerund (instead of an infinitive, for instance) because [the sense verb _see_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) can take a gerund complement. But that's not a fact about the clause itself so much as its environment.

Comment: So, if I’m understanding you correctly, you’re saying that these comparisons between a so-called “original” are irrelevant because they are simply something “abstract”. In other words, we have to assume that a sentence such as my passive example begins at... well... its own beginning. Simply put then, in a sentence such as “I saw him running down the street”, “him running down the street” is the gerund complement clause, like it’s abstractly molded passive form was, right?

Comment: In _I saw him running down the street_, yes, that is the gerund complement. The _him_ now functions as the object of _see_, which is why it can passivize and become the subject. This is all using [the "transformation" metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf), understand -- it's just a way to keep track of the thousands of sentence types in English.