# what's the difference between "to hear" and "to listen"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, differences, phrase-meaning, sense-verbs

I need to know the difference between "to hear" and "to listen". Could you explain it to me, please? I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: _Hear_ and _listen (to)_ are both active [sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), in this case the verbs for the sense of hearing. The difference between them is that _listen_ is a volitional activity (you do it on purpose), while _hear_ is a non-volitional activity (you can do it accidentally). The same distinction is what distinguishes the visual sense verbs _look (at)_ (volitional) and _see_ (non-volitional).

Comment: ...But there is a grey area. 'Hear' is broadened in say "Are you _hearing_ me?" (a near-sarcastic way of saying "You're not listening. Are you even _hearing_ me?"

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> *Hear* and *listen (to)* are both active [sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), in this case the verbs for the sense of hearing. The difference between them is that *listen* is a volitional activity (you do it on purpose), while *hear* is a non-volitional activity (you can do it accidentally). The same distinction is what distinguishes the visual sense verbs *look (at)* (volitional) and *see* (non-volitional).