# Is it a Participial Phrase?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, participles, present-participles

In this sentence:

> We saw Paul coming

I don't understand if the verb `coming` is a present participle.
Thank you!

Comment: _See_ is a [sense verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299). They allow gerund object complements like _Paul coming_. Gerunds are active participles that are the untensed verbs in a subordinate noun clause (in this case, the clause is the object of _see_).

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks, but why is not "Paul that was coming"?

Comment: You're sensing the action of Paul coming.

Comment: @Barmar is “coming” considered a verb or a noun?

Comment: It's a gerund, which means a verb functioning as a noun to represent the action.