# break, breaks, or broke?

Tags: past-tense

Here is a sentence from [BBC Learning English](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/lower-intermediate/unit-7/session-1/activity-2):

> And I saw that ship break in half.

Is this a correct sentence? I think I should use *broke*. Am I wrong?

Comment: I saw the man drowns?

Comment: You are wrong. A verb following _saw, heard, watched_ (for example) is in the infinitive.

Comment: [Sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) can take either gerund or infinitive complements. But _broke_ is past tense and _breaks_ is present tense, not either a gerund (_breaking_) or an infinitive (_break_).

Answer (score 0):

To see a ship `break in half` is to see the destruction of the ship in action.

To see a ship that `broke in half` is to see a ship after the destruction happened.

Comment: The second example isn't spot on. You may fix it by adding "that".

Comment: I would prefer *broken* in half.