# What is the word that means how a pen or pencil feels or sounds on paper?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes how the nib or tip of a pen or pencil feels or sounds on paper as one writes? It occurs to me that there might be a technical term.

Comment: Yes but it depends on the noise it actually makes. What noise were you thinking of?

Comment: We often use the relevant verb as a noun to refer to attributes like this. Particularly with verbs of perception (so we can ***feel*** the ***feel*** of fabric, or ***taste*** the ***taste*** of food), but the same principle also extends to more "functional" verbs - for example, the ***bite*** of your freshly-baked bread. So even if it doesn't yet have any currency, perhaps you could neologistically refer to *the **write** of the pen [nib]*. But even if calligraphers don't currently use ***write*** like this, I'm sure they wouldn't refer to the ***scratchiness*** of a favourite pen-nib.

Comment: ...but in practice, you might have to settle for something like *the **smoothness** of the nib*. Whatever - [glossary-of-fountain-pen-terminology](https://www.gouletpens.com/pages/glossary-of-fountain-pen-terminology) is a very long list which I'm not going all the way through. There *might* be a word there besides "balance" for the feel of the whole pen.

Comment: Single word requests should include a sentence and the context in which the word is used.

Comment: ...I've only got to the C's in that list, but I see there are "cursive" (smooth) nibs as well as "crisp" (good for italic writing) nibs. Maybe "cursivity" would be understood in contexts to mean the ease with which the nib rolls over the writing surface.

Answer (score 4):

[glossary-of-fountain-pen-terminology:](https://www.gouletpens.com/pages/glossary-of-fountain-pen-terminology)

> **Feedback**
> *The amount of **'bite'** or resistance perceived during a writing experience.*
> *This is a consequence of the relationship between the smoothness of a fountain pen nib and the smoothness of the paper being used.
>
> Also commonly referred to as **'tooth'**.*

---

I posted a comment pointing out the way a baker, for example, might refer to the ***bite*** of a biscuit or bread roll (how it feels to the teeth). I find it interesting to see that same "inverted verb" sense applied to the ***feedback*** of a calligraphy nib, and even more intriguing to see the alternative term ***tooth*** there.

---

Syntactically speaking, this use of ***feedback*** seems unexceptional (a pen gives feedback to the writer just as an audience gives feedback to a live entertainer). And I'd say ***bite*** is an example of "nounification" of a [***flip verb***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/2637) (where the verb "subject" is not the experiencer, but rather whatever is causing the sensation being experienced). But I don't know if there's a technical term for the "unusual" use of ***tooth*** in this context.

Comment: I suppose the 'feel' of clothing, a snooker cue, a mouse ... a situation, the 'look' of an object or situation, and the 'taste' of food are the archetypal examples. 'Feel' as a verb is a 'flip verb'. [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105098/taste-is-to-flavor-as-touch-and-sight-are-to-what/105101#105101).

Comment: I'm almost certain there's a technical term for what amounts to "reversing" the normal "agent/patient" relationships implied by a verb. To be honest, I was hoping someone like *you* might know it (in my understanding, you're good with technical terminology at this level, which sadly I am not).

Comment: - oh! is that what you meant? Is ***bite*** here a "flip verb"?

Comment: According to one article I've stashed, there are the Causative-Ergative alternation (also the Transitive-Ergative alternation), allowed by some verbs (for one-off occurrences) (John soon sold his Monet ... John's Monet soon sold) and the identical-looking middle alternation for stative senses (One can sell Monets almost at once ... Monets sell quickly).

Comment: I just thought of another exanple of what I'm supposing is a "flip verb". Not only might it be ***selling well*** - I could say *This wine **is drinking well***. I think "Causative-Ergative alternation" or something similar might have been what I had in mind. "Flip verb" I might just about be able to remember, but "Causative-Ergative alternation" is a bit much for long-term retention in my limited memory.