# What's the difference between 'see','look' and 'watch'?

Tags: meaning

'see','look' and 'watch are words that looks the same but aren't the same meanings, can some tell me what's the difference between them?

Comment: Look at this: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/444/what-is-the-difference-between-look-see-and-watch

Comment: Massively simplified: *see* does not necessarily involves any intention or effort. *Look does.* We use *watch* for things that (we expect) to move or change.

Comment: These are [sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), which have their own peculiarities.